# Accessing "form" property of a form ElementRef shows TypeScript error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this form in my template:

```
<form #heroForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
```

And I'm adding it as a ViewChild in the controller:

```
@ViewChild('heroForm') heroForm: ElementRef;
```

When I access the "form" property of it to see if it is valid, it shows a TypeScript error "Property 'form' does not exist on type 'ElementRef'.
".

```
if(this.heroForm.form.valid){
  this.submitted = true;
}
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/template-driven-form-demo-1tbb37?file=app%2Fuser-form%2Fuser-form.component.ts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply import ngForm directive

```
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
```

change your form declaration

```
@ViewChild('heroForm', { read: NgForm }) heroForm: any;
```

change you form validation condition

```
if(this.heroForm.valid){
    this.submitted = true;
}
```

Comment: I follow your advice, but `this.heroForm.valid` gives me an error because this.heroForm is undefined on `ngOnInit()`. I temporary solved adding your logic into `ngAfterViewInit()`. Any other suggests?

Comment: ngAfterViewInit() is fine to have.

Answer (score 1):

The `ElementRef` does not contain any property called `form`. However, the `#heroForm` that you have created is of type `NgForm` and it contains the `form` property.

You get the error because of the ts compilation. It cannot find a property named `form` in `ElementRef` and gives you error. At runtime, since its javascript, you dont get error and the code works fine.

To get rid of the error, you can read the property as `NgForm`, as given in @Boobalan's answer OR you can simply convert the type of the `heroform` to `any` instead of `ElementRef`.

Use `@ViewChild('heroForm') heroForm: any;`
instead of `@ViewChild('heroForm') heroForm: ElementRef;`

Comment: What about @ViewChild('configForm') configForm: NgForm;? Is that appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

Though Boobalan's answer is right, just to stick with typed check, you can avoid `any` and simply use type `NgForm` like:

```js
@ViewChild('heroForm') heroForm: NgForm;

if (heroForm.valid){
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read nativeElement property in ElementRef and in this invocation having some security vulnerabilities [1]. Try the below method. 
this.heroForm.nativeElement

[1] https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef