# How to convert ElementRef to HTMLFormElement in Angular Directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I am trying to cast ElementRef to HTMLFormElement which shows the following warning:
[image]

> Conversion of type 'ElementRef' to type 'HTMLFormElement' may be
>   a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other.
>   If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.

**Code:**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appSlValidate]'
})
export class SlValidateDirective {
  @Input() appSlValidate: any;

  constructor(private form: ElementRef) { 
    console.log(<HTMLFormElement>form);
  }

}
```

**Binding:**

```
<form [appSlValidate]>
```

If I directly try to inject `HTMLFormElement` instead of `ElementRef`, I am getting this error:

```
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[SlValidateDirective -> HTMLFormElement]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[SlValidateDirective -> HTMLFormElement]
```

Comment: Check out this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55293398/accessing-form-property-of-a-form-elementref-shows-typescript-error

Comment: Perhafs, you want inject ngForm `constructor(private form: NgForm){}`, see https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to establish a reference to the *native element* rather than to the *element reference*. I think you want this instead:

```
constructor(private form: ElementRef) { 
    console.log(<HTMLFormElement>form.nativeElement);
}
```